# Double rotation hinge

Tags: animation

I'm trying to animate three cubes: the white one rotate on itself; the red rotate with the withe one (remaining aligned with it); the blue one have to rotate with the two others, but simultaneously it must rotate around the center of the red one.

I did what follows and it didn't work:

1. I added the white one, and insert a keyframe at 1 with zero rotation, then i went to the 100 keyframe and add a keyframe with -45 z rotation;
2. I added the second one (red) and joined with the first (when i play the animation, the red one rotates correctly with the red;
3. I added the third one (blu), set his origin to the center of the red one (around which i want it to rotate), and add a delta transform of -45 z rotation.

But the center of the rotation of the blue one remains still at the original position of the red, so it doesn't rotate around the moving red one but around a fixed point.

I cannot understand hot to rotate the blue one around the center of the red while it moves, in a way that the blu cube still in line with the white and the red.

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Parent-child relation should be an easy solution, select blue one, select red one as well´( red will be active) and press Ctrl+P to make the red cube a parent, blue will follow red's movement

Answer (score 1):

1. give white a rotation keyframe
2. parent red to white
3. parent blue to red
4. set origin of blue to red's center
5. give blue a rotation keyframe

result:

[image]

Point 4 you can do like this:

1. select the red cube
2. Shift-S -> Cursor to selection
3. Select Blue cube
4. Object -> set origin to 3D cursor

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. The mistake was joining the objects... i have to parent them. Thank you!

Comment: If it helped, please check the checkmark left to my answer. Thanks.